# What is PDO, how is it related with SQL injection, and why I should use this?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

Actually I did google and got so many results, but I can't understand, because I'm new in this field.

So what is an easy way that what is PDO, why I should use this, what is SQL injection, etc. with an example?1

Actually now my code is like that.

#### config.php

```
<?php
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    $mysql_database = "testdb";
    $prefix = "";
    $bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
?>
```

#### insert.php

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $account_no = $_POST['account_no'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $save = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableamount (account_no, amount) VALUES ('$account_no', '$amount',)");
    header("location: index.html");
    exit();
?>
```

#### index.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="amount.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="addroom">
            Account Number<br />
            <input name="account_no" type="text"/><br />

            Amount<br />
            <input name="amount" type="text"/><br />

            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="button1" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

***PDO - PHP Data Objects*** is a database access layer providing a uniform method of access to multiple databases.

*It doesn't account for database-specific syntax, but it can allow for the process of switching databases and platforms to be fairly painless, simply by switching the connection string in many instances.*

[image]

Prepared statements / parameterized queries are sufficient to prevent first-order injection on that statement. If you use un-checked dynamic SQL anywhere else in your application you are still vulnerable to second-order injection.

Second-order injection means data has been cycled through the database once before being included in a query, and is much harder to pull off. AFAIK, you almost never see real second-order attacks, as it is usually easier to social-engineer your way in.

PDO is a bit slower than the `mysql`_*. But it has great portability. PDO provides single interface across multiple databases. That means you can use multiple DB without using mysql_query for mysql, mssql_query for SQL Server, etc. Just use something like `$db->query("INSERT INTO...")` always. No matter what database driver you are using.

So, for larger or portable project PDO is preferable. Even [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework) uses PDO.

---

**SQL Injection**

SQL Injection

SQL injection is a technique where malicious users can inject SQL commands into an SQL statement, via web page input.

Injected SQL commands can alter SQL statement and compromise the security of a web application.

---

**Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?**

The short answer is **NO,** PDO prepares will ***not defend you from all possible SQL-Injection attacks.*** Attacks [example](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string)

---

**How to use PDO?**

An example:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tables WHERE names = :name");
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name));
```

References

- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059
- [Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: +1 for 2nd order attacks, but please fix **Injecttion**, typo hurts my eyes, otherwise great answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply imagine this user input: `"1'); TRUNCATE TABLE accounts; --"`, with your statement, if the user know what db structure you have, can easily drop everything from the db (assuming the db user have the authorizations.

**Never use the user input directly in a sql query as you've done**, always escape/cast before use.

PDO - PHP Data Objects - is a database access layer providing a uniform method of access to multiple databases.

It doesn't account for database-specific syntax, but can allow for the process of switching databases and platforms to be fairly painless, simply by switching the connection string in many instances.

Please read [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) carefully, it explains why pdo should be used in php