# Error in Inserting data's in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I have a code which inserts data's in each tables in a specific database. After i run it this error come up

`"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis\database\insertdata.php on line 37"`

I check the codes for typo error but still i don't see any error on it maybe it is cause by a looping error

**This is my Code**

```
$db_name = array('morning_section_masterfile','evening_section_masterfile','afternoon_section_masterfile');
for($y=0;$y<=2;$y++)
{
   $db = mysql_select_db($db_name[$y],$connectDatabase);
   $tables = array('Pilot_Sections','Black_Sections');
     for($a=0;$a<=1;$a++)
     {
       //variable making
        $teacher = array ('Jane','Jeff','Liezeth','Loremas','Canada');
       $Default_Lname = 'Lorems';
       $Default_Fname = 'Vierzehn';
       $x=0;
       //Adding 30 students in one section
    do
    {
        for($i=0;$i<=30;$i++)
        {
            $section_teacher = $teacher[$x];
            $student_section = 'IT70'.$x.'E-C';
            $student_Lname = str_shuffle($Default_Lname);
            $student_Fname = str_shuffle($Default_Fname);
            $table = $tables[$a];
            $insert = "INSERT INTO $table (section_Teacher, student_Lastname, student_Firstname, student_Section) VALUES 
            ('{$section_teacher}','{$student_Lname}','{$student_Fname}','{$student_section}')";
            $insertdata = mysql_query($insert,$connectDatabase);
        }
    //check the number of students in a section section and adding another section
        if($i==31)
        {
            $x++;
            $i=0;
        }
    } while($x<=4)
  }
}
```

Comment: you missed a semicolon in line no 36...

Comment: WOWeeeee, my comment was their answers

Comment: @Jeff Please use PDO find the link in my answer ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a semi colon after while

```
do
    {
        for($i=0;$i<=30;$i++)
        {
            $section_teacher = $teacher[$x];
            $student_section = 'IT70'.$x.'E-C';
            $student_Lname = str_shuffle($Default_Lname);
            $student_Fname = str_shuffle($Default_Fname);
            $table = $tables[$a];
            $insert = "INSERT INTO $table (section_Teacher, student_Lastname, student_Firstname, student_Section) VALUES 
            ('{$section_teacher}','{$student_Lname}','{$student_Fname}','{$student_section}')";
            $insertdata = mysql_query($insert,$connectDatabase);
        }
    //check the number of students in a section section and adding another section
        if($i==31)
        {
            $x++;
            $i=0;
        }
    } while($x<=4);
```

Also as an advice don't use `mysql_*` as they are deprecated, Use `PDO` instead to prevent sql injection. Please refer [to my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292890/what-is-pdo-how-its-related-with-sql-injection-why-i-should-use-this/26293078#26293078) I've explained it in detail there.

Answer (score 0):

try this, you are missing semicolon in while loop at end.

```
<?php
$db_name = array('morning_section_masterfile','evening_section_masterfile','afternoon_section_masterfile');
for($y=0;$y<=2;$y++)
{
   $db = mysql_select_db($db_name[$y],$connectDatabase);
   $tables = array('Pilot_Sections','Black_Sections');
     for($a=0;$a<=1;$a++)
     {
       //variable making
        $teacher = array ('Jane','Jeff','Liezeth','Loremas','Canada');
       $Default_Lname = 'Lorems';
       $Default_Fname = 'Vierzehn';
       $x=0;
       //Adding 30 students in one section
    do
    {
        for($i=0;$i<=30;$i++)
        {
            $section_teacher = $teacher[$x];
            $student_section = 'IT70'.$x.'E-C';
            $student_Lname = str_shuffle($Default_Lname);
            $student_Fname = str_shuffle($Default_Fname);
            $table = $tables[$a];
            $insert = "INSERT INTO $table (section_Teacher, student_Lastname, student_Firstname, student_Section) VALUES
            ('{$section_teacher}','{$student_Lname}','{$student_Fname}','{$student_section}')";
            $insertdata = mysql_query($insert,$connectDatabase);
        }
    //check the number of students in a section section and adding another section
        if($i==31)
        {
            $x++;
            $i=0;
        }
    } while($x<=4);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I this `mysql` is old, you can change it to `mysqli`

You can use this:

```
<?php
//******  MySql Connect
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Connect failed";

    // if connection error script stop working
    exit();
    die();
}

//****** real_escape_string (Security)
$city = $mysqli->real_escape_string($city);

//****** RESULT
$query = "SQL";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo $row["Name"];
    }
    $result->free();
}

//****** Query
$mysqli->query("SQL");

//****** Close
$mysqli->close();

?>
```