# inserting user input data into database

Tags: php, insert

i have a form ("aud.php") with 3 fields:
YEAR: can be(fe,se,te,be)
SEMESTER: can be (1 or 2)
SUBJECT: can be (any VARCHAR datatype)

Now, i have a database ("einternals") with four tables (fe,se,te,be). Each table has 2 fields (sem1 or sem2). The problem is when i submit the form, the data is not getting inserted into the databse.

HERE"S the "aud.php" file:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","","einternals");
if (!$con)
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
echo "Go ahead and edit";
}
?>

<html>
<body background="bg1.jpg">
<h2 align="left"><a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a></h2>

<form action="add.php" method="post">
<h1 align="center"><u>ADD A SUBJECT</u></h1>

<p align="center">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspYEAR: <input type="text" name="year" required/></p><br>

<p align="center">SEM: <input type="text" name="sem" required/></p><br>

<p align="center">&nbsp&nbspSUBJECT: <input type="text" name="subject" required /></p><br>

<p align="center"><input type="submit" value="ADD" /></p>

</form>

<form action="delete.php" method="post">
<h1 align="center"><u>DELETE A SUBJECT</u></h1>

<p align="center">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspYEAR: <input type="text" name="year" required/></p><br>

<p align="center">SEM: <input type="text" name="sem" required/></p><br>

<p align="center">&nbsp&nbspSUBJECT: <input type="text" name="subject" required /></p><br>


<p align="center"><input type="submit" value="DELETE" /></p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

HERE's the "add.php" file:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
 mysql_select_db("einternals", $con);
 if('$_POST[sem]'==1)
  {
   $sql="INSERT INTO '$_POST[year]'(sem1)
   VALUES
   ('$_POST[subject]')";

   if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
}
else
{
 $sql="INSERT INTO '$_POST[year]'(sem2)
 VALUES
 ('$_POST[subject]')";

 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
 {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }
}
echo "Operation successful";


}
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: a syntax error that says "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''fe'(sem2) VALUES ('evs')' at line 1"

Comment: use $_POST[year] instead of '$_POST[year]'

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi i did and it is givin the same error

Answer (score 0):

a space needed in the query and no quotes needed.

```
instead of  - `"INSERT INTO '$_POST[year]'(sem1)
VALUES
('$_POST[subject]')"`
```

try this -

```
"INSERT INTO ".$_POST['year']." (sem1)
VALUES
('$_POST[subject]')"
```

Comment: here's what i did INSERT INTO ".$_POST[year]"(sem1) and its showin Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in C:\xampp\htdocs\einternals\add.php on line 12

Comment: missed that dot `".$_POST[year]."` and add the `space`

Answer (score 0):

try this for connection

```
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("einternals");
```

you have to use [mysql_select_db()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) for select your database
you are trying to make database connection as mysqli_* function

Comment: i dont think thats the problem cuz the connection worked fine with other scripts

Comment: it is best to call mysql_select_db() soon after - it takes just one argument, which is the name of the database you wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove single quotes and add a space between table and column names

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $_POST[year] (sem1)
   VALUES
   ('$_POST[subject]')";
```

Also `mysql_*` is deprecated use `PDO` instead to prevent your app from sql injection have a look at: [What is PDO , how it's related with sql injection & why i should use this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292890/what-is-pdo-how-its-related-with-sql-injection-why-i-should-use-this/26293078#26293078)

Answer (score 0):

Try to added proper quoting to post data for check and in query

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
 mysql_select_db("einternals", $con);
 if($_POST['sem']==1)
  {
   $sql="INSERT INTO ".$_POST['year']." (sem1) VALUES ('".$_POST['subject']."')";
   if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
     die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
}
else {
 $sql="INSERT INTO ".$_POST['year']." (sem2) VALUES ('".$_POST['subject']."')";
 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }
}
echo "Operation successful";
}
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

**Note** :- `mysql_*` has been deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `pdo`

```
    you need to escape post data to prevent `sql injection`
```

Comment: i think you should add white space after concatenate year
$sql="INSERT INTO ".$_POST['year']." (sem2) VALUES ('".$_POST['subject']."')";

Comment: your variable should return like this.
`"INSERT INTO 1999(sem2) VALUES ('value');`
but this is invalid query between table and field name must have a space.