# Should we remove any characters from passwords?

Tags: php

Or should we just escape and prepare the password and let the user have every character and special character possible? I mean at the end of the day, the people trying to SQL inject will fail and it will just escape the string, and am I right in saying there's no need to punish the normal, law abiding citizen for other people's wrong doings?

Comment: You can use PDO, have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292890/what-is-pdo-how-its-related-with-sql-injection-why-i-should-use-this/26293078#26293078

Comment: What kind of characters are you referring to? ASCII and Unicode should be fine, but you might want to disallow control characters in user input.

Comment: I do Tushar :) Hence the prepare statement :P

Comment: Yes, you should always escape any text input by user before entering into database

Comment: Some characters have multiple encodings which could conceivably be keyboard or input-device dependent. Disallowing them or always converting them might save some customer frustration.

Answer (score 3):

No, do not remove any characters from passwords. If you are following best practice and using [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/password_verify), the only thing you’ll be storing in your database are harmless hashes. Removing any characters might weaken the strength of their password for nothing.